# I don't receive my email verifications in Trello

Tags: trello, email

I've just been suggested to use Trello, but I have one problem.

I get the message to verify my email address... but I don't receive the email to verify the address. What to do?

Comment: and yes.. I have tried to resend it.

Comment: have you checked your spam folder?

Answer (score 1):

With the number of different email systems out there, you can probably imagine that these mails sometimes slip through the cracks. Before we dig deeper, we just want to make sure you have checked your spam filter and retried sending the mail using:

http://trello.com/resendValidate

If you've done both of those, and the mail hasn't shown up after a few hours, please let us know at support@trello.com.

In the vast majority of cases reported, the mail is being sent but is being misdirected after being accepted by the user's mail service. We can get you logs to take back to your mail provider so they can investigate.